# How can I have report values filtered from webdatarocks?

Tags: angular, datagrid, pivot-table, webdatarocks

I'm using WebDataRocks report from https://www.webdatarocks.com but when I try to use the method report.getData({}) the following error happens:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfR6n.png)

I need the current values filtered to export in json file.

Thanks

Comment: Please include your code as part of your question, there is not nearly enough information provided for someone to be able to understand and help you with your issue.

Comment: @rlipka could you fix this issue?